# How to handle None value in nested functions and exception

Tags: python, exception, nonetype, divide-by-zero, nested-function

updated to

My goal is that

1. to get q = getQuotient() line is called only when both x and y are not None
2. to get calc1() stop running and go back to main to run b.calc2() AFTER getting the ZeroDivisionError.
3. to get b.calc2() line gets executed whether b.calc1() got caught in the ZeroDivisionException or not when x and y can be None as well as numbers including 0.

---

I added my questions in comments below.

My goal is that

1. to get q = getQuotient() line is called if only x and y are not None
2. to get b.calc2() line gets executed whether b.calc1() got caught in the ZeroDivisionException or not when x and y can be None as well as numbers including 0.

a.py

```
import b
if __name__ == "__main__":
    b.calc1()
    print("Done with 1")
    b.calc2()
    print("Done with 2")
```

b.py

```
def calc1():
    x = getX()
    y = getY()
    if not x or not y:
        return

    q = getQuotient(x, y)
    if q:
        print(q)
    # does more stuff here
    # and I would like this calc1() to stop here, stop running if getQuotient() gets the ZeroDivisionError.

def getQuotient(x, y):
    try:
        return x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("zero division error happened.")
    # what can, should I do here? 
    # I would like calc1() to stop running and go back to main if it gets ZeroDivisionError.
    # How's "return None" since "if quotient" line will stop processing any further if y is zero?
    # if I raise, it terminates the program, which means b.calc2() won't run. I need it to run, though.

# ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a.py

```
import b
if __name__ == "__main__":
    b.calc1()
    print("Done with 1")
    b.calc2()
    print("Done with 2")
```

b.py

```
    def calc1():
    x = getX()
    y = getY()
    if not x or not y:
        return

    q = getQuotient(x, y)
    if not q:
        return
    else:
        # The other lines 
        # of code to run if it
        # is not 'None'
   
def getQuotient(x, y):
    try:
        return x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("zero division error happened.")

P.S using 'return None' will also do in your version of b.py but it will return None automatically in case of exception.
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion. I would like to keep that ZeroDivisionError exception within the getQuotient function, if possible. I also have updated my goals/code a little, could you take a look again?

Comment: This will do. You are not required to raise any exceptions here or return None, it will return None by default in case of exception

Comment: if there are more lines after that "if not x and/or not y", it'll keep going after getting caught in the exception, won't it? how can I get out of the calc1() after getting into the exception?

Comment: I have made the changes to my answer. In case of Exception it will just return to main otherwise it run the following lines of code

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't understand the 'not x', but why didn't you just type:

   if x and y:
   q = getQuotient(x, y)
2. The ZeroDivisionError is caught so the code will print that it happened and move on.

Comment: 1. sorry there was a typo, i meant *if not x and not y. it was for goal #1. 2. i need it to stop processing calc1() after that ZeroDivisionError, and go back to main, print "Done with 1" and keep going with b.calc2(). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Adjusted. Tell me if I missed anything

Comment: With 1, getQuotient doesn't run if both x and y are None, though, doesn't it? For 2, currently, after the "q = getQuotient(x, y)" line, q is None and calc1() keeps running and does #... lines. I would like to find a way that makes calc1() to stop running and goes back to main :'(